# How do I recover an Azure VM from the free trial?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I were using an Azure free trial and now is done. As soon I noticed the trial was over, I bought one Linux VM. But how can I transfer the data from the old one to the new?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "data" you mean content of your hard disks its most likely tied to a storage account. You could detach the disk from the previous VM and attach it to the new one. I'm not sure what the process is for linux but I know its possible.

Comment: Thanks for your reponse. How do I detach the disk? Or how I can download it?

Comment: @DanielRamos You can look for the storage tab on the azure portal and check for the "vhd" container

Comment: @DanielRamos You can check this url and associated links for more info. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-how-to-detach-disk/

Comment: I can't access the free trial VM dashboard. I can't click the arrow on the VM to access it. Here is a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/FgVqPr2.png

Comment: @DanielRamos The cloud service is stopped i think. you'll need to activate it by adding a subscription and putting payment details .. they won't charge you for a few weeks .. just the mandatory $1 USD to confirm that the card works ... you'll have enough time to get your data out in a few hours.

Comment: Ok, I bought another subscription and now I can acces the VM, but I cannot start it... What a horrible experience I'm having with Azure... :(
http://i.imgur.com/1ORUj5u.png

Comment: @DanielRamos Please check that the cloudservice attached to the VM is running.

Comment: Ok the cloud service wasn't running, but when I started it up again, it throws me an error that it can't turn on the VM. Also, I can't manage the disk to download it.
http://i.imgur.com/nPeKld0.png
http://i.imgur.com/cdU2Wff.png

Comment: @DanielRamos You can manage the disk if you go to storage > container > vhds

Comment: I can't access the container tab... Look here: https://mega.co.nz/#!g9MTTRxI!PqylfHvYYHO60tOdqdkJumPdKJd-AZSkzv0f_3xO2g0
BTW, thanks for all the time you are taking helping me, thanks a lot relly :)

Comment: @DanielRamos I couldn't see anything in the link .. maybe an image like you've been sending ..

Comment: Wow, now I can start up the VM and download the VHD file... I believe that I had to wait some time... Thanks a lot really!!